# Learn to Program by Chris Pine book question

Tags: learning, books

I don't know where to post this, so sorry if this is the wrong place.

I bought the book Learn to Program by Chris Pine on my iPad, I will be travelling for about two days so want to read this book and learn to program obviously but won't have access to a computer so is it worth reading this book while travelling? I flicked through it and has some exercises so was wondering what I should do. thanks

Comment: The important thing to do when learning to program is not to read, but to write code based on what you read.  For such a short stretch, consider it an initial reading.

Comment: Check out apps such as `Code To Go` on the iPad - also web sites such as http://codepad.org - these will let you experiment with simple programs in various different programming languages when you don't have access to a "real" computer.

Comment: I won't have Internet connection :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would read through it, but be prepared to go through it again with a focus on working the exercises now that you understand the theory. This may be a better way to go about reading a programming book in the long run. The tough part would be resisting writing code. It's a nice feeling when you get new things to work.

Comment: +1 for the tough part. You feel restless if you see code and you cant implement it!

Comment: Ok thanks. Will defo go over it when I'm at my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a PC, IDE or even text editor to read Ruby code. Ruby syntax is very natural and that book is written in Ruby so go ahead. It's a nice book and enjoyable.

Comment: Thank you, so it is defeitnly a good book to read and learn from? With out the need to worry about not having a PC? :)

Comment: I'm a C and Objective-C primarily developer. But learn ruby with that book. Also has good tips about software design principles.